# Is there any way we can get new users to read a short guide to asking questions?

Tags: discussion

And by short I mean, no longer than a paragraph. Let me explain.

We are closing questions because the question is too broad/vague, or too localized. I remember i used to use a program called Stomp, it made bassdrums. It came with a manual, and the manual had 5 questions that you had to answer before you could use the program. This forced the user to know a little about the program, it was `playful` (ie not condescending) and really helped me learn the program.

I don't expect each time a user posts a question, to be faced with a few questions to make sure they understand the stackexchange `party line`, but it would be superb if first time questioners had 4 or 5 multiple choice questions to establish that they understand what kind of quality we like to have here. If we don't we will end up doing more boring administrative work unfit for humans, and make people feel inadequate for not asking good questions.

With a bit of creative wording we can convince people to take the time to understand that blender.stackexchange is the best thing since sliced bread, and everyone can participate and be a valuable member of the community if they want. So from the very start we ask that they accept a few generally accepted ways to communicate with the rest of us.

- No long meandering questions, boil down the question to the core if you can.
- It is OK to ask many questions, but break them up into different posts so they can be answered separately.
- Don't be too worried about spelling or grammar, at least don't let it stop you from asking questions. Avoid using 'text-speak' as a courtesy to us.
- If you ask a question, please stay around for a while to see if it has answers or comments looking for clarification.

BAM.

thoughts? I didn't have time to make this shorter, sorry.

Comment: +1. To "Don't be too worried about spelling or grammar" can we add something like "but please don't use text-speak"? Things like "wat have u tried" on StackOverflow drive me crazy...

Comment: fixed it up a little, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I don't really think we can do much. They're already supposed to read the about/faq or at least the quick summary before their first question(which I'm sure many of them ignore).

Comment: maybe we can re-adjust some attitudes towards the user agreement, it can be better.

Comment: Well, the FAQ is out there, but...

Comment: [Not any more...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182812/192187)

Answer (score 1):

make it a part of a "new user tutorial" page / link.

I don't consider myself unschooled in computers or systems (programming since 1974, business consultant since 1995) and just discovered site yesterday. I run the 2-minute drill on initial contact, but suspect initial Q&A submitted didn't demonstrate skill level experience should expect. extended view of other postings helped.

I suggest offering (or making a currently available page much more visible... I didn't find it) users an intro to the site. use examples of good and bad, reasons for each, and add links to followup pages in useful areas (the  command for instance). keep the 2-minute page option, perhaps a link at the bottom.

good hunting. have found the site useful, though some parts have been 'not so intutive' as I expected. (in fairness, part of my issues may be hardware related... I am using a very old 1st gen iPad on iOS 5.1.1.)